# Settings file does not have settings listed in error log

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode lists these errors:

```
2024-03-30 14:51:04.141 [error] Following setting is deprecated: "python.linting.mypyEnabled"
2024-03-30 14:51:04.141 [error] All settings starting with "python.linting." are deprecated and can be removed from settings.
2024-03-30 14:51:04.141 [error] Linting features have been moved to separate linter extensions.
2024-03-30 14:51:04.141 [error] See here for more information: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting
2024-03-30 14:51:04.141 [error] Please install "mypy" extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.mypy-type-checker
```

I don't have any such settings in my settings file. Ctrl+, shows settings.json:

```json
{
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "workbench.layoutControl.enabled": false,
    "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Program Files\\python312\\python.exe",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": "explicit"
    },
    "files.defaultLanguage": "python",
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict",
}
```

Also, mypy is definitely installed:

```
Mypy Type Checker v2023.6.0
Microsoft microsoft.com 167,479 (6)
Type checking support for Python files using Mypy.
Disable  Uninstall Switch to Pre-Release Version
This extension is enabled globally.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are they in your workspace settings?

Comment: if you're using multi-root workspace, check also your .code-workspace file. if you're using profiles, check your profile settings.json.

Comment: @wjandrea Aha - those are in my workplace settings.